# Leaving out blank fields in fusion info windows

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I've mapped a number of addresses with various fields of data in my table. How can I show a field for which I have data for one address but make sure it does not show in the info window for the addresses that have no such data?

For example, some of my addresses are properties that have been demolished. My table includes that info and the cost of the demolition. Is there something I can write in the code to make the "Cost of demolition" field show in the windows for the addresses that have a value for that field, and not show in those that do not?

My apologies for such a basic question. I'm a journalist just learning his way around this stuff. I found one other question about displaying photos that seemed somewhat related but I wasn't sure that answered my question.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you using the GMap API and Javascript?  Or are you looking for a solution via the Fusion Table UI?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this using a little programming using the Fusion Tables Layer in the Google Maps API. It is not possible using the Fusion Tables UI alone. An example of how to change info window content based on data in the table is available here:

https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/change_infowindow_content